# R: Data frame column specific data manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
x <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3],val0=c(100,200,300),val1=c(400,500,600),val2=c(700,800,900))
```

I want to divide odd columns with a specific number n1(say) and even columns with another number n2 (say). So, the result I want is:

```
>n1<-2
>n2<-5

id    val0    val1   val2
a     50      80     350
b     100     100    400
c     150     120    450
```

Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function `seq()` to generate values for column numbers and then subset those columns. For even columns start with 2 and for odd star with 3. Then replace selected columns with the same selected columns divided by number you are interested in.

```
x[,seq(2,ncol(x),2)]<-x[,seq(2,ncol(x),2)]/n1
x[,seq(3,ncol(x),2)]<-x[,seq(3,ncol(x),2)]/n2
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly disguised `for` loop:

```
x[] <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) x[, i]/ifelse(i%%2, 2, 5))
```

And just for kicks:

```
x[] <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) x[, i]/if(i%%2) 2 else 5)
```